# Select items for database that I don't have

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

This is how I get some BOOKs listed in my application:

```
$sessionid = '000000000015';

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("
SELECT 
    BOOKS_NEW.ID AS BOOKID,
    BOOKS_NEW.BOOK_NAME,
    MAX(USERS_BOOKS.DATE_MODIFIED) AS MAXDATE,
    CASE WHEN ? IN (SELECT USERID FROM USERS_LIKES WHERE BOOKID = BOOKS_NEW.ID) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS DID_I_LIKE_IT

FROM 
    USERS_BOOKS

INNER JOIN
    BOOKS_NEW ON BOOKS_NEW.ID=USERS_BOOKS.BOOKID



GROUP BY
    USERS_BOOKS.BOOKID

ORDER BY 
    MAXDATE DESC LIMIT $start, $finish");

    $stmt -> execute(array($sessionid));
```

## Result

> [[{"BOOKID":"000000067","BOOK_NAME":"Find a four leaf clover","MAXDATE":"2015-05-04 15:18:25","DID_I_LIKE_IT":"No"},{"BOOKID":"000000999","BOOK_NAME":"Go to a Houston Rockets game","MAXDATE":"2015-05-04 15:18:16","DID_I_LIKE_IT":"No"},{"BOOKID":"000001000","BOOK_NAME":"Go to a Houston Texans game","MAXDATE":"2015-05-04 15:18:09","DID_I_LIKE_IT":"No"}}]

However, I want to list only those BOOKs that the user (`$sessionid`) does NOT have.

This is how I list the current BOOKIDs of the user:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT USERS_BOOKS.BOOKID FROM USERS_BOOKS
    WHERE USERS_BOOKS.USERID = ?");
$stmt -> execute(array($sessionid));
```

RESULT:

> [[{"BOOKID":"000000001"},{"BOOKID":"000000003"},{"BOOKID":"000000999"}]]

In the end result I want to get a json like the one in the first one, but without the `BOOKID = 000000999` as it is present in the second one.

I tried using

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM BOOKS_NEW WHERE BOOKS_NEW.ID = USERS_BOOKS.BOOKID)
```

but it gave me an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your subquery. You're referencing `USERS_BOOKS.BOOKID`, which is not within the scope of your subquery. What you need to do is pass the list of books already liked

```
WHERE BOOKS_NEW.ID NOT IN (SELECT BOOKID FROM USERS_LIKES WHERE USERID = ?)
```

Then pass your user ID into here. That should select all the books that the user likes and generate a list that that main query can ignore.

Comment: It gives me null as well. Btw it should be `WHERE BOOKS_NEW.ID NOT IN`

Comment: I found a problem in the subquery. Check out my update

Comment: It looks good. I need to test this because my real query is much more complex. I'll get back, thanks!